# How do test all combinations of parameters in DataRows

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest

Suppose I have a test method like so:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow( 0, 0, 0 )]
[DataRow( 0, 0, 1 )]
[DataRow( 0, 1, 0 )]
[DataRow( 0, 1, 1 )]
[DataRow( 1, 0, 0 )]
[DataRow( 1, 0, 1 )]
[DataRow( 1, 1, 0 )]
[DataRow( 1, 1, 1 )]
public void ReallyCoolTest( int a, int b, int c )
{
    // some really cool test code that uses a, b, and c
}
```

This tests against all combinations of a, b, & c equaling 0 or 1. Just two values in three parameters and it takes 8 `DataRow` lines!

What I'd really love to do is something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataMatrix( {0,1}, {0,1}, {0,1} )]
public void ReallyCoolTest( int a, int b, int c )
{
    // some really cool test code that uses a, b, and c
}
```

I'd like to specify some values for each parameter and have all combinations tested. Is there anything like that using MS test?

*Note: I am aware of the `DataSource` attribute. However, I'd like to have the values in-code and not in an external file.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could come up with is this:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestThing
    {
        [CombinatorialTestMethod]
        [DataRow( 0 , 9 )]
        [DataRow( 1 , 2 )]
        [DataRow( 3 , 4 , 5 , 7)]
        public void TestMe( int a , int b , int c )
        {
            if ( b * 2 == c )
                throw new Exception( "blah!" );
        }
    }

    public class CombinatorialTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
    {
        private object[][] argsArrays = new object[][] { };

        private List<object[]> argumentsList = new( );

        public override TestResult[] Execute( ITestMethod testMethod )
        {
            // Get arrays of arguments, then construct arguments list
            List<object[]> argsArraysList = new( );
            foreach ( DataRowAttribute parameters in testMethod.GetAttributes<DataRowAttribute>( false ) )
            {
                argsArraysList.Add( parameters.Data );
            }
            this.argsArrays = argsArraysList.ToArray( );
            this.ConstructArgumentsList( );

            // Invoke the test
            List<TestResult> results = new( );
            foreach ( object[] args in this.argumentsList )
            {
                try
                {
                    TestResult result = testMethod.Invoke( args );
                    results.Add( result );
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    results.Add( new TestResult( )
                    {
                        Outcome = UnitTestOutcome.Failed ,
                        TestFailureException = e ,
                    } );
                }
            }

            return results.ToArray( );
        }

        private void ConstructArgumentsList( )
        {
            int num_params = this.argsArrays.Length;

            int[] indices = new int[num_params];

            bool done = num_params == 0;
            while ( !done )
            {
                // Get next arguemnt combination
                object[] args = new object[num_params];
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < num_params ; i += 1 )
                {
                    args[i] = this.argsArrays[i][indices[i]];
                }
                this.argumentsList.Add( args );

                // increment indices
                for ( int i = num_params - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i -= 1 )
                {
                    indices[i] += 1;
                    if ( indices[i] >= this.argsArrays[i].Length )
                    {
                        indices[i] = 0;

                        if ( i == 0 )
                        {
                            done = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not going to use it because I'm not 100% happy with it yet, but I may fiddle some more and publish something later.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @JMekker's answer I  refactored the code a bit to generate multiple test cases beforehand, instead of having multiple test results under a single test.
I also added exclusions support and moved parameter values attributes to parameters in order to be more explicit.

```csharp
[TestClass]
public class TestThing
{
    [TestMethod]
    [CombinatorialData]
    [ExcludeCombination(9, 1, 4)]
    public void TestMe([DataValues( 0 , 9 )] int a ,[DataValues( 1 , 2 )] int b , [DataValues( 3 , 4 , 5 , 7)] int c )
    {
        if ( b * 2 == c )
            throw new Exception( "blah!" );
    }
}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DataValuesAttribute : Attribute {
    public object?[] Values { get; }

    public DataValuesAttribute(params object?[] values) {
        Values = values;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ExcludeCombinationAttribute : Attribute {
    public object?[] Values { get; }

    public ExcludeCombinationAttribute(params object?[] values) {
        Values = values;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CombinatorialDataAttribute : Attribute, ITestDataSource {
    public IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo) {
        // Retrieve parameters values
        var values = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DataValuesAttribute>()?.Values ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Combinatorial test requires all parameters to have the [DataValues] attribute set")).ToArray();
        var indices = new int[values.Length];

        // Retrieve any excluded combinations
        var excluded = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<ExcludeCombinationAttribute>(true);

        // Combine all the values
        while (true) {
            // Create new arguments
            var arg = new object?[indices.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++) {
                arg[i] = values[i][indices[i]];
            }

            // Check if needs to be excluded
            if (!excluded.Any(e => e.Values.Zip(arg).All(v => v.First?.Equals(v.Second) == true))) {
                yield return arg!;
            }

            // Increment indices
            for (int i = indices.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                indices[i]++;
                if (indices[i] >= values[i].Length) {
                    indices[i] = 0;

                    if (i == 0)
                        yield break;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetDisplayName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] data) {
        if (data != null) {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} ({1})", new object[2]
            {
                methodInfo.Name,
                string.Join(",", data)
            });
        }

        return null!;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate your test parameters during runtime with the [DynamicData attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.dynamicdataattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022). You can give the name of a method that returns an IEnumerable of object[]. These are used as the parameters for your test.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetData), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void ReallyCoolTest(int a, int b, int expected)
{
   // ...
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData()
{
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
  {
     for(int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
     {
        for(int k = 0; k <=1; k++)
        {
           yield return new object[] {i,j,k};
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: My main issues with this are: 1) the data isn't next to the test function, 2) I have to define a data function for each test. I'm going to mess around with defining my own Attribute but I will accept this answer if I don't have any luck because this does help.

Comment: Unfortunately , this is the best solution I know. I don't know if this helps you, but Nunit has the [`Combinatorial`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/combinatorial.html)  attribute, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I re-implemented NUnits approach in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77425689/4503491

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Xriuk's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75531690/4503491) answer

I re-implemented NUnit's Combinatorial, Sequential and Values attributes.

Usage:

```
[TestMethod, Combinatorial]
public void CombinatoralValuesIterationTestMethod([Values] Season season, [Values] bool boolean) => Console.WriteLine($"{season} {boolean}");

[TestMethod, Sequential]
public void SequentialCombinatoralIterationTestMethod(
[Values(1, 2, 3)] int param1,
[Values("A", "B")] string param2) => Console.WriteLine($"{param1} {param2 ?? "null"}");

[TestMethod, Combinatorial]
public void CombinatoralIterationTestMethod(
[Values(1, 2, 3)] int param1,
[Values("A", "B")] string param2) => Console.WriteLine($"{param1} {param2 ?? "null"}");
```

--

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValuesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object?[] Values { get; }

    public ValuesAttribute(params object?[] values)
    {
        Values = values;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CombinatorialAttribute : Attribute, ITestDataSource
{
    public IEnumerable<object?[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        List<object?[]> values = new List<object?[]>();

        foreach (var parameter in methodInfo.GetParameters())
        {
            var attribute = parameter.GetCustomAttribute<ValuesAttribute>() ??
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{parameter.Name} should have a [Values] attribute set");

            if (attribute.Values.Length == 0)
            {
                if (parameter.ParameterType.IsEnum)
                {
                    values.Add(Enum.GetValues(parameter.ParameterType).Cast<object>().ToArray());
                    continue;
                }

                if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    values.Add(new object[] { true, false });
                    continue;
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException($"[Values] {parameter.ParameterType} {parameter.Name} is only valid for Enum or Boolean types. Consider using the attribute constructor.");
            }

            values.Add(attribute.Values);
        }

        var indices = new int[values.Count];

        while (true)
        {
            // Create new arguments
            var arg = new object?[indices.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
            {
                arg[i] = values[i][indices[i]];
            }

            yield return arg!;

            // Increment indices
            for (int i = indices.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                indices[i]++;
                if (indices[i] >= values[i].Length)
                {
                    indices[i] = 0;

                    if (i == 0)
                        yield break;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public string? GetDisplayName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object?[]? data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            return $"{methodInfo.Name} ({string.Join(", ", data.Select(e => e ?? "null"))})";
        }

        return null;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class SequentialAttribute : Attribute, ITestDataSource
{
    public IEnumerable<object?[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        List<List<object?>> values = new List<List<object?>>();

        foreach (var parameter in methodInfo.GetParameters())
        {
            var attribute = parameter.GetCustomAttribute<ValuesAttribute>() ??
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{parameter.Name} should have a [Values] attribute set");

            if (attribute.Values.Length == 0)
            {
                if (parameter.ParameterType.IsEnum)
                {
                    values.Add(Enum.GetValues(parameter.ParameterType).Cast<object?>().ToList());
                    continue;
                }

                if (parameter.ParameterType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    values.Add(new List<object?> { true, false });
                    continue;
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException($"[Values] {parameter.ParameterType} {parameter.Name} is only valid for Enum or Boolean types. Consider using the attribute constructor.");
            }

            values.Add(attribute.Values.ToList());
        }

        var longest = values.Max(e => e.Count);

        foreach (var list in values)
        {
            if (list.Count < longest)
            {
                var diff = longest - list.Count;
                list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat<object?>(null, diff));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++)
        {
            yield return values.Select(e => e[i]).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public string? GetDisplayName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object?[]? data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        {
            return $"{methodInfo.Name} ({string.Join(", ", data.Select(e => e ?? "null"))})";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```